# Ruby Exception Handling: reverse stack-trace order

Tags: ruby, exception, stack-trace, reverse

When a ruby app hits an exception, regardless of framework, the stack trace all present itself   with the most important information first. It's generally very long I find myself scrolling back up the command line searching out where it starts, when really I need to just read the first one or two lines.

I would like to rearrange the output to reverse the order the stack-trace is presented in. Perhaps I am not wording this correctly but I could not find how to do this with a quick search.

Has anyone had any experience working with exception outputs that could point me in the right direction?

So for example:

```
$ rackup
/Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/app.rb:19:in `include': wrong argument type String (expected Module) (TypeError)
    from /Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/app.rb:19:in `block in <class:Application>'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1385:in `configure'
    from /Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/app.rb:17:in `<class:Application>'
    from /Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/app.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.3/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.3/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
    from /Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/config.ru:7:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
$
```

I'd like to see the line:

```
/Users/Ascended/Ruby/sinatra/genye/app.rb:19:in `include': wrong argument type String (expected Module) (TypeError)
```

at the end rather than the beginning of the output, effectively reversing the order of the output.

Comment: Exceptions can be printed out in a lot of different places--in what context were you trying to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks dan, I've updated my question with an example, these sorts of errors are the ones I am trying to affect.

Answer (score -1):

If you're catching an exception, you could try something like this:

```
begin
  bad_code
rescue Exception => e 
  puts e.backtrace.reverse
end
```

Comment: hum, so from this pattern, I could change Ruby's Exception class to reverse the output on an application level, but what about running a commandline function like rackup, the output would not be affected by what would be programmatically defined in the application would it?